# Sorting by alternate numbered rows without losing data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

[image: I want to sort by Sr.No. in ascending order in such a way that I get both Name and ID in the same order.Since the ID has no numbering alongside I am facing difficulty in doing so, can anyone please help .]

I want to sort by Sr.No. in ascending order in such a way that I get both Name and ID in the same order.Since the ID has no numbering alongside I am facing difficulty in doing so, can anyone please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Sort By Every Other Row

[image]

Add a helper column with the following formula in the first cell (row 2)...

```
=IF(MOD(ROW(),2),C1+1,2*A2-1)
```

... and copy down.

Now sort this column instead.

**Edit**

Here's another way to spill the sorted data in another place:

[image]

```
=LET(data,A2:B13,iCol,1,
    i,INDEX(data,,iCol),
    f,IF(i>0,2*i-1,0),
    s,VSTACK(0,DROP(IF(f>0,f+1,0),-1)),
SORTBY(IF(data="","",data),f+s))
```

Answer (score 4):

P.b's answer is so elegant I can't compete.

But just for the record I took the question as requiring each person's data to be kept on two rows so came up with this:

```
=LET(range,A2:B9,
ser,INDEX(range,,1),
fill,SCAN(0,ser,LAMBDA(a,c,IF(c="",a,c))),
sort,SORTBY(range,fill),
IF(sort="","",sort))
```

[image]

Comment: That might just as well have been the intention, now that I look at the question again. It's unclear, but regardless she has an answer.

Comment: Yes my version is a bit long-winded. My justification I suppose is that I wanted to define the range once and make a subrange where necessary, so if you wanted to change the range or make it dynamic you would only have to do it in one place. It also reflects my thought processes and programming background where you name things. I can almost feel a much bigger question about 'programming style' in let and lambda coming on.

Answer (score 3):

in Microsoft 365 you could use:
`=SORTBY(WRAPROWS(B2:B9,2),TOCOL(A2:A9,1))`
or:

```
=LET(a,A2:B9,
SORTBY(WRAPROWS(DROP(a,,1),2),TOCOL(TAKE(a,,1),1)))
```

Or if you want them stacked the way they were:

```
=LET(a,A2:B9,
TOCOL(SORTBY(WRAPROWS(DROP(a,,1),2),TOCOL(TAKE(a,,1),1))))
```

In older Excel you could use the following formula (dragged down/left):

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$9,
               MATCH(SMALL($A$2:$A$9,ROW(A1)),
                     $A$2:$A$9,
                     0)
               +COLUMN(A1)-1),
         "")
```

or stacked (dragged down):

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$9,
               MATCH(SMALL($A$2:$A$9,INT((1+ROW(A1))/2)),
                     $A$2:$A$9,
                     0)
               +ISEVEN(ROW(A1))),
         "")
```

Comment: @TomSharpe I decided to update my answer with a downwards spillable/draggable version as well, ignoring the `sr no` column data in the data results.